# Helmholtz coil - I don't understand the circuitry

Tags: amplifier, field

I work in a testing laboratory.  We recently introduced in our repertoire a testing method using Helmholtz coils to generate a magnetic field.

In order to have a magnetic field I need to have current on that wire. In order to have current I need a closed circuit. What baffles me is the connection from the two amplifier's outputs to the coils.

Coils specifications from calibration documents and manufacturer documents:

[image]

The coils are hidden under some sort of material meaning that I cannot see the wires. Both of the coils have 3 connectors.

- First coil: blue, white, brown.
- Second coil: brown, black, purple.

The connections from the amplifier's output to the coils are color coded, meaning for example that the wire with blue color goes in the input/output with the same color, like in the following picture:

[image]

In order to try and figure how the current flows from both of the outputs I started the system and in the software I generated 1000A/m in DC mode. I used a multimeter to measure to potential difference in multiple points. You can see the following picture. The dashed line is the multimeter and the black cross is the positive line from the multimeter.

Does anyone have a clue how does this work? The only thing that I could figure out based on the coil specification is that one coil is made of silver because of the very low resistance and there is a bridge connection on the brown connectors.

[image]

Comment: What do you understand about mutual coupling and impedance for a transformer?

Comment: You'll have to specify which hardware you're using. A normal Helmholtz coils setup usually has 2 terminals and no need for an amplifier.

Comment: Maybe you could show us more of the manufacturer's data on this. I would guess that one coil is for low frequency high field strength and the other low inductance coil is optimized for higher frequency modulation. X_L of the coils @150kHz is 1653 ohms and 63 ohms respectively.

Comment: 'Helmholtz coils' are two identical coils with a specific spacing. You have some specific manufacturer's take on the concept, that's peculiar to them. You need to provide make / model / serial number to stand any chance of finding out what they have intended with those connections.

Comment: The transfer function is basically the turns ratio, but impedance can be resonant or matched for MPT/IPT. Better question SVP?

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestions and technical things that I almost forgot. I'll research on my own and try to come with an answer. Kudos.